# Having conditions in WHERE statement in SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two queries returning the same set of columns.

```
SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IN ('123')

SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.Address IN ('123')
```

If the user gives first_name as input the result of first query has to be chosen, if the user gives Address as input, then the result of second query has to be chosen.

I tried using (A.FIRST_NAME = '123' or B.Address = '') when user gives the first name and (A.FIRST_NAME = '' or B.Address = '123') when the user gives the middle name but it's making the query to run forever.

```
SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IN ('') OR B.Address IN ('123')
```

I would like to have suggestions from my fellow experts.

Comment: I see some potential design problems here.  Why are the first and middle names being stored in completely separate tables?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, It's just an example I created. The real world scenario is different but the concept is same.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, Modified the query with meaningful names. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JSVJ, when you say 'run forever', are you saying it's very slow? Have you created any indexes for these tables?

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach would be this:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.age, b.address
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id 
WHERE (a.first_name = @first_name OR @first_name IS NULL)
  AND (a.address = @address OR @address IS NULL);
```

This works where

- only the first name is given
- only the address is given
- both are given (in that case only the rows matching both conditions are returned)
- none are given (in that case all rows are returned)

The DBMS will have to find an execution plan that works fine for all conditions. This may be full tables scans that aren't necessarily slow, but this won't be lightning fast either.

This is different with a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.age, b.address
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.first_name = @first_name
UNION
SELECT a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.age, b.address
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.address = @address;
```

This works where

- only the first name is given
- only the address is given
- both are given (in that case all rows matching at least one condition get returned)
- none are given (in that case no row is returned)

For this query the DBMS can use an index on `first_name` and another on `address` (provided you created these indexes) and the query will be very fast.

This `UNION` query is after all just another way of merlely using the `WHERE` clause `WHERE a.first_name = @first_name OR a.address = @address`. But by splitting the query you give the DBMS's optimizer the hint that it can look at this as two separate queries for which it can use different indexes. With a perfect optimizer, this hint would not be necessary and the DBMS would see this itself. I am pretty sure that MySQL's current optimizer needs this hint.)

Comment: . . Your parentheses were wrong in the first query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thank you for correcting this.

Answer (score 1):

From the query from your question posted below:

> `SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IN ('') OR B.Address IN ('123')`

This equates to `WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL OR B.Address IN ('123')`. It's important to consider ordering in where clauses and the ramifications of the ordering *(indexes on columns is a major factor and the order of columns in the index)[EDIT]*.

The quoted query will actually return all the records where the first names are not null and the record where the address = '123'.

I would suggest using an if statement to execute the correct query based on the user input. Something like this:

```
SET @isAddress := 1; -- variable that is set to 'Y' for yes, if the user inputs an address. If it's not 1 or greater, then the user has inputted a first name.
SET @userInput := '123'; -- variable that contains the user's input (either address or firstname). 
IF @isAddress > 0 THEN
    SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
    FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
    WHERE B.Address = @userInput;
ELSE
    SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
    FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID 
    WHERE A.FIRST_NAME = @userInput;
END IF;
```

*[EDIT]*
On second thought you could use a simplified query like this:

```
SET @isAddress := 1; -- variable that is set to 'Y' for yes, if the user inputs an address. If it's not 1 or greater, then the user has inputted a first name.
SET @userInput := '123'; -- variable that contains the user's input (either address or firstname). 

SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE (@isAddress > 0 AND B.Address = @userInput)
   OR (@isAddress = 0 AND A.FIRSTNAME = @userInput);
```

Comment: I don't understand "ordering in where clauses". Do you think that it makes a difference whether to say `WHERE a=b OR c=d` or `WHERE c=d OR a=b`? It doesn't (or shouldn't at least). And `WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IN ('') OR B.Address IN ('123')` equals `WHERE B.Address IN ('123')`, because we can assume there is no entry with first_name = ''. It does not equal `WHERE A.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL OR B.Address IN ('123')` which would probably be all rows (except for the case that entries without a first name exist).

Comment: Yes, it will make a difference whether you order a query `WHERE a=b OR c=d` or `WHERE c=d OR a=b`. I don't know the context here, so I can't say which option is more optimal, but for example:

Comment: ... but for example:
If `c=d` is a trivial statement like with say a variable not being `null` then it's better to put use `WHERE c=d OR a=b` because the trivial statement is evaluated first.
There may be a performance difference between the two.
Finally, I am aware that a query optimiser will most likely evaluate the trivial condition first; but in more complex cases, it may not.

Comment: A DBMS will consider the conditions in `WHERE` and `ON` in whatever order it sees appropriate and beneficial. It would be weird, if it obeyed the order in which the conditions are listed. And it doesn't. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4052a0276a71dc0bc668b549083b0d27

Comment: True, but it depends on the complexity of the query. DBMS optimisers don't always get it right, so it's always best to write a query in the most optimal way. I added a note about indexes to the answer. It's something I didn't mention above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in the  hope of lazy evaluation of `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.FIRST_NAME ='somename' OR
B.Address = '123'
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, A.Age, B.Address
FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.FIRST_NAME ='somenam%' AND
B.Address LIKE '12%'
```

The second variant suits for the four cases:

1. When both clauses are `= ''` it will return the unfiltered set (`LIKE '%'`);
2. When `A.FIRST_NAME = ''` and the `B.Address != ''` it will return the set filtered by `B.Address LIKE '12%'`;
3. When `A.FIRST_NAME != ''` and the `B.Address = ''` it will return the set filtered by `A.FIRST_NAME LIKE 'somenam%'`;
4. When both clauses are `!= ''` it will return the set filtered by both fields (`LIKE 'somevalue%'`).